# How to pass data to an external assembly User Control through MEF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, wpf-controls, mef

I am a beginner in MEF. According to my requirement I have to show the multiple plugin UI according to the selection of plugin. For that I have to pass plugin related data to the external plugin UserControl.

```
[InheritedExport(typeof(IConnect))]

public interface IConnect{}
```

Below code is using to initializing the external UI from the main application,

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IConnect))]

public IEnumerable<Lazy<IConnect>> Plugins;
```

....

```
var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(@"C:\TestDll\");

var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);

container.ComposeParts(this);

var childControl = SelectedPlugin as UserControl;
```

//Here I have to pass the required data to the usercontrol. How to do this?

```
Dockpanel.Children.Add(childControl );
```

Could you please suggest a way to pass data to the external user control

Comment: What exactly do you need to pass to the user control?

Comment: I have to pass the plugin related data which stored in database. It is a xml file need to pass to the plugin view.

Answer (score 0):

Our entire team here at work has been using MEF for years now, and I'm reasonably familiar with how it works.

To get everything bootstrapped off the ground, the first thing to do is ensure that a ***common MEF container*** is shared between your main application and the user control in your external assembly.

If you don't have a common MEF container, then your MEF imported classes will never be able to communicate with the host application, as they will be living in separate MEF universes.

Once you have a common container, anywhere you want to bootstrap a class out of the container, you can use something like this:

```
var test = MefContainer.GetExportedValue<ITest>();
test.Run();
```

### Q. How do I add MEF to my project?

A. Using NuGet, search for "microsoft composition", and add MEF 2.

### Q. So how do we create this shared MEF container?

A. As follows:

- Follow through a tutorial such as [From Zero to Proficient with MEF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376033/From-Zero-to-Proficient-with-MEF).
- Create a class library that is shared between your imported control, and the host application.
- In this class library, create a singleton class called `MefContainer`. This means that anybody that wants to grab something out of the MEF container can reference this singleton to obtain the MEF container. The MEF container contains classes from all of the auto-discovered assemblies in the directories that we want to scan.

### Q. How do I communicate with the user control?

A. Add this class to your shared class library:

```
public interface ITest
{
    string SharedValue { get; set; }
}

[Export(typeof(ITest))]
public class Test : ITest
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Test()
    {

    }

    public string SharedValue { get; set; }
}
```

Now, both the host app and the user control can grab an instance of the same class out of the MEF container:

```
var test = MefContainer.GetExportedValue<ITest>();
var result = test.SharedValue;
```

By default, classes that are obtained from the MEF container are singleton's, unless we explicitly say that we want non-shared classes.

### Q. How about adding Reactive Extensions (RX)?

It's ok to have a class with shared values. But it's nicer if one component can fire events off, and any other component can listen to this event.

To do this, add RX to your project using NuGet (search for "reactive extensions", add "Reactive Extensions - Main Library").

Add a `Subject` to your shared class:

```
private Subject<string> MyEvent { get; set; }
```

Now, if you have a MEF reference to this shared class, you can send an event out:

```
var t = MefContainer.GetExportedValue<ITest>();
t.MyEvent.OnNext("hello");
```

And, any other class can subscribe to these events:

```
var t = MefContainer.GetExportedValue<ITest>();
t.MyEvent.Subscribe(
    o =>
    {
        Console.Write(o);
    });
```

If code is already running in the MEF composition container, then there is no need to use `MefContainer` to get at the container. You can simply MEF import the shared communication class using the constructor:

```
public interface IClassRunningInContainer
{
}

[Export(typeof(IClassRunningInContainer))]
public class ClassRunningInContainer : IClassRunningInContainer
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ClassRunningInContainer(ITest t)
    {
        t.OnNext("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

### Final Notes

Don't make the mistake of using MEF as a general dependency injection (DI) solution. You will run into roadblocks further down the road, as MEF is does not have the level of built in diagnostics to find out if things have gone wrong, compared to a dedicated dependency injection solution, such as Unity.

The ideal pattern is to use MEF for importing whole assemblies, then use Unity as your day to day DI container.